# Debian AWS auto-starting script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, debian

I have a modified AWS basicPubSub function to transfer data to the AWS IoT core, I want the script to run at start-up.

I have added this script into, make it executable and updated the init.d

```
/etc/init.d
chmod 755 LOMAWS.sh 
sudo update-rc.d LOMAWS.sh defaults
```

But the script does not start, how can I make it run from start up?

```
clear
echo "LOM AWS Script starting"
cd /home/pi/Documents/awsiot/aws-iot-device-sdk-python/samples/basicPubSub
sudo python basicPubSub.py -e "XXXXXXXX-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com" -r root_CA.crt -c XXXXXXXX-certificate.pem.crt -k XXXXXXX-private.pem.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [UserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)?

> By default, user data scripts and cloud-init directives run only during the first boot cycle when an instance is launched

Comment: Of course it cannot start as there is no internet connection, have to see how to get around it with the script and userdata